# Shapiro diagram with ggtern package using function geom_polygon_tern

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to draw a Shapiro (combustion) diagram using the `ggtern` package of `R`.

I succeeded drawing the diagram (very easy with the package) and now I would like to add a polygon in order to highlight some area of the diagram where combustion is not possible.

To do so, I would like to use the `geom_polygon_tern` function of this package. I tried the following code :

```
library(ggtern)
#Import necessary data = different atmosphere possibilities expressed in concentration percentages (sum = 1)
mydata <- data.frame(inertant = c(0.78,0.81,0.80), combustive = c(0.17,0.17,0.17), combustible = c(0.05,0.02,0.03))

#data frame used to store polygon vertices coordinates
df <- data.frame(coord1 = c(0.6,0.6,1.0), coord2 =c(0.0,0.4,0.0) , coord3 = c(0.4,0.0,0.0))

#drawing the diagram with ggtern package
ggtern() + geom_point(data=mydata,size=1,shape=1,aes(x=inertant,y=combustible,z=combustive))+
theme_rgbg() + geom_polygon_tern(data = df, aes(x=coord1,y=coord2,z=coord3))
```

Unfortunately I get the following error:

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos): object 'level' not found
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos): object 'level' not found
```

I tried the same idea in `ggplot2` (on which `ggtern` is based) and it works. So I don't really understand what I am doing wrong and I don't get the problem from the error message (I am new to R).

**SOLUTION**

I managed to get the code working by changing `geom_polygon_tern` to `geom_polygon`

[shapiro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPgLk.png)

Answer (score 0):

`ggtern 2.0.1`, which was published on CRAN a couple of days ago after completely re-writing the package to be compatible with `ggplot2 2.0.0`. A summary of the new functionality in `ggtern 2.0.X` can be found [here](http://ahref.io/UuED1):

Anyway, `geom_polygon_tern` no longer exists, the standard `geom_polygon` works fine.

[image: solution]

```
#drawing the diagram with ggtern package
ggtern() + 
  geom_polygon(data = df,    aes(x=coord1,y=coord2,z=coord3)) +
  geom_point(  data = mydata,aes(x=inertant,y=combustible,z=combustive),
               shape=1,colour='red') +
  theme_rgbg()
```